# Finding Facebook Ads for a business

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, google-ads-api

Is there any way to find out if a business/domain is running any ADS on facebook ?

Either it might be using facebook ads API or any other API which can provide this data?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into the matter in the past and the short answer is no.

Some advertisers want to maintain anonymity and therefore Facebook would never disclose that kind of information. Advertising is where all there money is coming from!